# How is generate session_id?

Tags: php, session

When I see info from phpinfo(), `session.hash_function` value is `0`, this means that session hash function is `MD5`, right?

But result from `echo strlen( session_id() );` is **26**.

Question: Why  **26** and not  **32** ?

Comment: `session.hash_bits_per_character` "compresses" the hash, resulting in a shorter hash.

Answer (score 2):

The higher you set session.hash_bits_per_character the shorter your session_id will become by using more bits per character. The possible values are 4, 5, or 6.

When using sha-1 for hashing (by setting ini_set('session.hash_function', 1) the following session string lengths are produced by the three session.hash_bits_per_character settings:

- 4 - 40 character string
- 5 - 32 character string
- 6 - 27 character    string